# REPLACE showing error that the column name is invalid

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

Hi need to replace the name of a document in static HTML that is stored in a 2016 SQL Server database.

The table name is **contract.departmentInfo** and the column with all the HTML is called **staticHtmlForAdmins**

So I'm trying to use the REPLACE function, but it keeps telling me that the column name is invalid even though I know it's the correct name.

Here is my SQL:

```
SELECT REPLACE(staticHtmlForAdmins,'2019_Rule_additions.pdf','New_Rules_2020_2021.docx');  
from contract.departmentInfo
where deptID = 374352
```

Is there any reason why the above wouldn't work?

Thanks!

Comment: Then the column name *is* invalid. What's the table's schema (ie the CREATE TABLE command)? You have to post that at least so people can reproduce the problem. If `REPLACE` didn't work thousands of developers and DBAs would have noticed. Are there extra or missing characters perhaps? Perhaps your account doesn't have permission to query that column, so it can't even see it? Querying the wrong database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is normal

```
SELECT REPLACE(staticHtmlForAdmins,'2019_Rule_additions.pdf','New_Rules_2020_2021.docx');  
from contract.departmentInfo
where deptID = 374352
```

Remove the ; after

```
REPLACE(staticHtmlForAdmins,'2019_Rule_additions.pdf','New_Rules_2020_2021.docx')
```